# Unsure about syntax/methods. I believe my code should work but it does not

Tags: javascript, arrays

Prompt: Given a positive integer num, return the sum of all odd Fibonacci numbers that are less than or equal to num. The first two numbers in the Fibonacci sequence are 1 and 1. Every additional number in the sequence is the sum of the two previous numbers. The first six numbers of the Fibonacci sequence are 1, 1, 2, 3, 5 and 8. For example, sumFibs(10) should return 10 because all odd Fibonacci numbers less than or equal to 10 are 1, 1, 3, and 5.

The code I wrote for this is:

```
function sumFibs(num) {
  const arr = [1,1];
  let sum = 0;
  for(let i = 2; i <= num; i++){
    let queef = arr[i - 1] + arr[i - 2];
    arr.push(queef);
  }
  for(let j = 0; j < arr.length; j++){
    if(arr[j] % 2 != 0){
      sum += arr[j];
    }
  }
  return sum;
}

console.log(sumFibs(6));
```

but i get 23 when it should be 10, I'm not sure why this doesn't work because i feel this would work in java. I have also tried to do arr[i] == queef but that also does not work. I am missing something or should this work?

Comment: Your initial loop adds an extra number. Some `console.log` statements or breakpoints would help identify issues like this quickly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your error relies in

```
for(let i = 2; i <= num; i++){
```

I believe you're generating an amount of numbers till num instead of the value itself. Try with something like this (I tried to keep your style):

```
function sumFibs(num) {
  if (num === 1) return 1;
    
  const arr = [1,1];
  let sum = 2;
  for(let i = 2; i <= num; i++){
    let queef = arr[i - 1] + arr[i - 2];
    arr.push(queef);

    if(arr[i] % 2 != 0 && queef < num){
        sum += arr[i];
    }
  }
  return sum;
}

console.log(sumFibs(6));
```

Answer (score 1):

Welcome Bethany, enjoy your new coding journey.  If you change line 4 in your code to:

```
for(let i = 2; i < num; i++){
```

it returns 10

Answer (score 0):

It should be `< num` in the first for loop. Since array indexes start from `0` and not `1`, when you type `<= 6` it makes an array with 7 numbers in it.